# missing something obvious in .htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My goals are simple:

1. anything strating with with `/special` should go to `/SpecialHandler.php`
2. everything else should go to `/index.php`

My basic configuration is written like this but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/special(.*)/?$ SpecialHandler.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^.*/?$ index.php [L]
```

The following is what is happening:

- localhost - works fine
- localhost/bla_bla-bla%20bla - works fine
- localhost/special/ - **goes to `index.php` instead of `SpecialHandler.php`**
- localhost/special/fu/bar/bat -  **goes to `index.php` instead of `SpecialHandler.php`**

This has got to be something obvious that I'm missing.

Comment: ¿Where is the htaccess file located? If it is in `/special`, which would be the normal location in a local server, I don't think your rules will work as they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the first / of the special rule :

```
RewriteRule ^special(.*)/?$ SpecialHandler.php [L,NC]
```

it should work

-- complete working htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /a/
RewriteRule ^special(.*)/? SpecialHandler.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*/?$ index.php [L]
```

url :

```
http://localhost/a/special => special
http://localhost/a/special/really => special
http://localhost/a/index.php => index
http://localhost/a/foobarbaz => index
```

Comment: Are you sure that will work for the forth example?  I'm having trouble testing this.  `^/special(.*)?$` seems to work better for me, but I don't entirely know how mod_regex parses

Comment: Here is a [demo](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=^%2Fspecial%28.*%29%3F%24&input=%2Fbla_bla-bla%2520bla%0A%2Fspecial%2F%0A%2Fspecial%2Ffu%2Fbar%2Fbat) if what I'm talking about

Comment: Yes it does work with multiple slashes. The problem is that your RewriteBase is set to /, thus, the rule is read as ^//special/ which is never found.

Comment: If I drop the "SpecialHandler.php" and put in something that isn't there, I get an appropriate error.  However, when it is there it still winds up going to `index.php`

Comment: @Joe Your handler must be redirecting to index.php in this case. The .htaccess does what it have to do

Comment: All I have in there is `print "Special Handler"` (and in `index.php` all I have is `print "Base Index"` - all that I ever get is `Base Index` printed out.

Comment: I edited my reply to add the full working set I have here. Make sure you fixed your .htaccess file

Comment: What version is your Apache server?  It's not working locally nor on my remote host.  I wonder if there's an underlying configuration issue causing it not to work.

Comment: bash-3.2$ /opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix)
Server built:   Sep 25 2012 23:30:57

Comment: I upgraded Apache and it worked just fine.  That seems to be the primary issue I was facing.  I read through the release notes for the Apache update and the mod_rewrite module and didn't see much, but the version differences definitely made it work.